# UI component re-usability

Tags: tomcat, user-interface, reusability

how it is possible to package/share a UI component in more than one WAR, having only one version of the code?

Example:
-We develop one searchUser (IU & Controller) component. 
-We use it webApp1 and webApp2
-If we need to make some changes in searchUser (IU & Controller), we dont need to make changes in two places, we only need to re-package webApp1 and webApp2.

Thanks

Update:
Thanks to Chad
[Howto re-use War resources between Wars with Maven War Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142081/reusing-jsp-and-its-controller-in-more-than-one-war)

Comment: stuff it in its own jar and redistribute in every war, no?

Comment: And a Way to doing it automatically is maven I Guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stuff it in its own jar and redistribute in every war, no?

Options:

- if you already use maven, use it
- there are other options like maven (gradle and the like)
- put the jar in a central folder and implement the fetching in a prebuild step or your build script